# Convergence of open sets covering a closed set in the state space of a right-contiunous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $t \rightarrow X_t$ be right-continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a closed set. I want to know if either $X_t \in \Lambda$ or $X_{t-} \in \Lambda$ holds (for a fixed $t$) when given the following:

$X_t \in A_n$ for all $n$, where $A_n := \{x: d(x, \Lambda) < 1/n \}$ and $d(x, \Lambda)$ is the distance between a point $x$ and the set $\Lambda$.

So $\Lambda \subset A_n$ for all $n$. I think it's possible for both $X_t$ and $X_{t-}$ to lie in $A_n \setminus  \Lambda$ for all $n$. E.g. $X$ might be discontinuous at $t$, such that $X_t$ and $X_{t-}$ lie just outside the boundary of $\Lambda$.

That is, it's not guaranteed that either $X_t$ or $X_{t-}$ should lie in $\Lambda$. Am I correct?

Comment: The condition $X_t\in A_n$ for all $n$ is equivalent to $X_t\in\overline{\Lambda}$, but $\Lambda$ is closed, so $X_t\in\Lambda$.

Comment: I don't see why $X_t \in A_n$ for all $n$ implies $X_t \in \overline{\Lambda}$. Since $A_n$ is open, there might be a non-empty region $A_n \setminus \overline{\Lambda}$ in which $X_t$ could lie. Or?

Comment: "For all $n$" is the key. Your condition says that $d(X_t, \Lambda)<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, which means $d(X_t, \Lambda)=0$.

Comment: Right! I was thinking that “for all n” would still imply that $d(x, \Lambda) > 0$. I.e. no matter how large $n$ becomes, the distance is never exactly zero. Why does it eventually become zero?

Comment: Can you phrase the question more clearly? What are you assuming and what do you want tot hold? Also, why does it matter that $t\to X_t$ is right continuous if $t$ is fixed for your assumption?

Comment: @harisf Well, what nonnegative number is less than $1/n$ for all $n$?

Comment: Note that $X_t$ and $X_{t-}$ are just two fixed points. They may be defined in terms of a function, but the symbols themselves just represent points, not the function, nor the limit process used to define $X_{t-}$ Since all we know is that the function is right continuous, we don't even know if $X_{t-}$ exists. And if it does exist, it could be anything. It bears no relation to $X_t$ itself. So all that you know about where $X_t$ is says nothing about $X_{t-}$.

Comment: $d(X_t, \Lambda)$ does not "eventually become zero". It is just some fixed number $\ge 0$. What we find out from the condition is that this single unchanging number is $< \frac 1n$ for all $n$. Thus Brifa's question.